# Disable pre-emptive validation of empty textfield

Tags: forms

On my form I have some fields and I set form['#required_error'] to generate a message on empty fields.
Works OK on select and option fields, but not on textfields.

It seems there is a (kind of ajax) validation before, which gives a pop-up with "fill in this field".

How can I disable pre-emptive validation of empty text fields, so that I can generate my onw messages

Comment: That's the browser responding to the `required` attribute on the inputs. You'll need to remove that attribute if you don't want the browser to provide its own validation (or convince each user to disable it)

Comment: It is not the required attribute, it is the HTML5 required attribute that starts this validation. It is only set for textfields and textareas, it is not set for e.g. selectfields. Maybe it is done somewhere in the twig's.

Comment: Correct, the `required` attribute on the input as I said...not to be confused with the `#attributes` property found in the server-side render array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'fill in this field' message is browser specific HTML5 error handling.
Which is triggered before the form is submitted.
Only modern browsers show this, and it may currently not be consistent between browsers.

About this behaviour is an interesting discussion here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1797438.

If you have your own logic in place to assist the user with problems in the form you can disable HTML5 validation altogether by setting the `novalidate` attribute on the `<form>`. More specific is setting the `formnovalidate` attribute on a submit button.

In a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) you can add the following line:

```
$form['#attributes'] += ['novalidate' => TRUE];
```

Comment: Saved my day!!!!